# XSL 1.0 If not like

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSL to create a PDF document template, and don't want certain fields to display if the line value is zero.

I have tried

```
<xsl:if test="line_value != 0">
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="unit_quantity"/>
</xsl:if>
```

But this doesn't work. I think because line_value is of the format £0.00.

I'm trying to get it to do `line_value NOT LIKE '£0.00'`, but I don't think that's the correct syntax for XSL.

Comment: You don't need *NOT LIKE* - *not equal* should work just as you intend: `test="line_value != '£0.00'"`

Comment: I think the problem is that `xsl:with-param` cannot be nested within an `xsl:if`. You can reverse the statements though, and do `<xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:if test="line_value != 0"><xsl:value-of select="unit_quantity" /></xsl:if></xsl:with-param>` (so the `value` parameter would be empty of `line_value` is zero).

Comment: You could use `test="not(contains(line_value, "0.00'))"`.  -- Note that `xsl:with-param` cannot be a child of `xsl:if`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that below is your XML:

**INPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<body>
    <line_value>£0.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£1.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£0.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£2.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£0.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£5.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£0.00</line_value>
    <line_value>£1.00</line_value>
</body>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="body/line_value">
                <xsl:if test="number(translate(., '£', '')) != 0">
                    <num>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </num>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```